# How can i show TP = Tan θ and OP = sec θ?

Tags: geometry

I saw this question and im not sure just how i can figure it more or less i dont even understand what steps i should do in order to solve it.The question is about secants and tangents and how can i solve similar problems?, here's the question:

> The names tangent and secant refer to the lengths of the tangent TP and TP
>    secant OP in the diagram , where the tangent TP subtends an angle θ at the centre O of the circle of radius 1. Show that TP = tan θ and OP = sec θ .

[image: What am i supposed to show?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As drawn above, construct a circle of radius $1$ with center $O$. Construct the segment $OT$. Select a point $P$ outside the circle, and construct the segment $OP$. The line $OP$ is a secant line as it intersects the circle at two places, and $TP$ is a tangent line to the circle as it intersects the circle at one point.

But why? Let $\theta = \angle TOP$. Then $\tan \theta = \frac{|TP|}{|OT|}$, but $|OT| = 1$. So $\tan \theta = |TP|$, the tangent line. Similarly, $\sec \theta = \frac{|OP|}{|OT|} = |OP|$, the secant line.